# Map from indiscrete topological space to usual topological space

Tags: general-topology

How can we say that a map from Indiscrete topology on Real numbers to Usual topology on Real numbers is a CONSTANT map?

Comment: This definitely needs more context - what have you tried? where did you get stuck? and how did this question arise? *(In particular, I'm 100% certain you're missing a key word here ...)*

Comment: I want to ask that is the map f:(R,ζ)→(R,ζ') is continuous? where R= set of real numbers,ζ= indiscrete topology on R, ζ'= any other topology on R.

Comment: "the map" What map exactly? Also, should both topologies be the same (you've written "$\zeta$" for both of them)? You should ask precisely the specific question you're trying to answer.

Comment: I want to ask that is the map f:(R,ζ)→(R,ζ') is continuous? where R= set of real numbers,ζ= indiscrete topology on R, ζ'= any other topology on R.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see the apostrophe on the second zeta. But again you *have not* actually specified a map ("the map" - *which* map? there are many different maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Ok , suppose (X,d) is indiscrete topological space and (X,ζ) be any topological space then we know that every map f:(X,ζ)→(X,d) is continuous but does it's coverse is true?

Comment: Ah, that's a question that makes sense *(almost - I presume that by "converse" you mean "every map from the indiscrete topology to another topology is continuous"?)*. Remember that continuity means that every open set on the *right* pulls back to an open set on the *left*. The indiscrete topology has "few" open sets - indeed, the fewest possible - so think about examples where the other space has "lots" of open sets ...

Comment: We know that a map f:X→Y (X, Y are topological spaces)is continuous if and only if inverse image of each open set of Y is open in X. Now my question coversly for the map f: (X,d)→(X,ζ), suppose G be an arbitrary open set of (X,ζ) the it's inverse image f⁻¹(G)=X is open set of (X,d) as it is indiscrete topological space and thus f : (X,d)→(X,ζ) should be continuous. Is it correct?

Comment: Why is $f^{-1}(G)=X$? In general that's not true.

Comment: Oh , it's my fault . In general it's not true .Means converse need not be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is a function from $\Bbb R$ in the indiscrete topology to $\Bbb R$ in the usual topology then $ f$ is continuous iff it is constant. A constant map is continuous between all spaces, and for the reverse we just need to note that if $f$ has at least two distinct values, say $p$ and $q$, then $f^{-1}[\{p\}]$ and $f^{-1}[\{q\}]$ are disjoint closed non-empty subsets (by continuity and standard properties of inverse images) and in the indiscrete topology that cannot happen: there is only one non-empty closed set, namely the whole space. So a non-constant map is not continuous.

Any map in the other direction ( so to the indiscrete topology) is always continuous.